# Google Warning: There is no deobfuscation file associated with this App Bundle

Tags: google-play, warnings, proguard, deobfuscation

I am still getting the warning from Google Play Store: "There is no deobfuscation file associated with this App Bundle.", having followed the instructions to deal with it.

My proguard-rules.pro says

```
# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFiletype here
```

I am generating a signed bundle with no errors or warnings, and the Google explanation says "When publishing using Android App Bundles this file is included automatically as part of the app bundle content. "

Using Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2

So why am I still getting the warning?, or how shall I work out why I am still getting the warning?